# how to access browser %variables% (enclosed in percent % signs)

Tags: firefox, browser, environment-variables, urlencode, console.log

In various browsers you can find these type of variables `%VAR%`

In firefox `about:config` you can find:

```
%LOCALE%
%VERSION%
%OS%
%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%
```

etc..

Where are those variables stored or set, and how to console log their value?

Comment: in https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Nightly_update_infrastructure, it's mentionned those variables are preprocessed. https://aus2.mozilla.org/update/1/%PRODUCT%/%VERSION%/%BUILD_ID%/%BUILD_TARGET%/%LOCALE%/%CHANNEL%/update.xml
"This is preprocessed to make the required substitutions. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [firefox source code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/d36cf98aa85f24ceefd07521b3d16b9edd2abcb7/toolkit/components/urlformatter/URLFormatter.jsm) file named URLFormatter.jsm, you can see how those variables are declared.

For example, `%OS%` return a value from `Services.appinfo.OS`

`%LOCALE%` returns `Services.locale.appLocaleAsBCP47`

`%CHANNEL%` returns  `UpdateUtils.UpdateChannel`

`%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%` returns  `AppConstants.MOZ_GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY`

Those functions are defined within the prototype `nsURLFormatterService` but to access AppConstants for example, you need to use a custom firefox build,; like Firefox Nightly or enable experimental mode.

Those variables can be imported within a custom addon, and importing them using ChromeUtils.

```
const { AppConstants } = ChromeUtils.import(
  "resource://gre/modules/AppConstants.jsm"
);
```

Here is the more advanced [documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/lint/linters/eslint-plugin-mozilla/use-chromeutils-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

console.log(navigator) will give you information that the browser has